# Address class for all countries

Tags: class, business-logic, street-address

I am trying to develop global Address class for my global e-commerce project. 
It must be possible to construct different address forms for different address formats so I need global address class for that reason.
Which properties must be common in this class? What is your suggestions about it?

Note: I found this [site](http://www.addressdoctor.com/en/countries-data/address-formats.html) where there are address formats for many countries.

Comment: Which language? You could develop an abstract base class with specializations for the different countries.

Comment: Which properties must be in the base class?

Comment: All that you need when you are *using* the addresses. The base class defines the interface.

Answer (score 0):

[The UPU](http://www.upu.int/en/resources/postcodes/addressing-systems.html) has the documentation and recommendations you're looking for.